# Octave goes in Waiting... when solve() function is used

Tags: octave

I've installed and loaded the symbolic package that becomes available from optim package to obtain the syms function (like in MATLAB) but when I use solve() function the command window goes in Waiting mode like

```
Waiting..........
```

My code is given below:

```
syms s T K D1 D2 D3 theta1 theta2 theta3 J1 J2 J3

eq1 = (s * D1 + K + J1 * s ^ 2)* theta1 - K * theta2 == T;
eq2 = -K * theta1 + (J2 * s ^ 2 + K + D2 * s) * theta2 - D2 * s * theta3 == 0;
eq3 = -D2 * s * theta2 + (D3 * s + J3 * s ^ 2 + D2 * s) * theta3 == 0;

S = solve(eq1, eq2, eq3)
```

but if I manually solve it by inverse method, it gives the answer instantly. Kindly help to solve this bug.

Comment: What do you mean with "manually solve"? Do other simple inputs like solve(x==1) work?

Comment: By manually solve, I mean `X = inv(A)*B;`. Also, simple equations don't work too. For example I tried: `eq1 = x+3*y ==5; eq2 = 2*x-y == 10; S = solve(eq1, eq2);` and still the same problem